# Querying a search through all contacts

Tags: java, android

I am trying to search up contacts with a search query, but something doesn't seem to be working:

```java
public class Callbacks implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    Context mContext;
    String query;
    public static final String QUERY_KEY = "query";
    public static final String TAG = "Callbacks";
    public Callbacks(Context context) { mContext = context; }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderIndex, Bundle args) {
        query = args.getString(QUERY_KEY);
        ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();
        Uri contentUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(query));
        Uri fullContentUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        return new CursorLoader(
            mContext, // Context
            contentUri, // Search this
            null, // Projection
            null, // Selection
            null, // Selection args
            null // Sort Order
            );
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor cursor) {
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) return;
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        Log.d(TAG, "Search Query: " + query);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String displayName =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
            Log.d(TAG, displayName);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {
    }
}
```

The full contact name list is Amy, Kevin, John, Joe, Oscar. 
If I put "j" as the query, I only get John in the cursor (even though I'm supposed to get John and Joe):

`D/Callbacks: Search Query: j
             John`

If I put "a" in the query, I get nothing in the cursor even though I should get Amy:

`D/Callbacks: Search Query: a`

If I replace the contentUri with fullContentUri (defined in the gist) so it's not a filtered uri, I get all the contacts as expected regardless of the query:

`D/Callbacks: Search Query: j
             Amy
             Kevin
             Joe
D/Callbacks: Oscar
             John`

so something is not right with my filtering...but according to this: https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names it looks like I'm doing everything right.

Comment: what is the size of cusor.getcount()?

Comment: Huh I get a cursor count of 1 of searching "a", and a cursor count of 3 when searching "j". What's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you are moving the cursor to the first item calling the method `moveToFirst`. Then you are moving directly to the second one calling the method `moveToNext`. In that case, you are missing the first element always. The solution should be to iterate directly from the first item:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) return;

    Log.d(TAG, "Search Query: " + query);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String displayName =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
        Log.d(TAG, displayName);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Ah that was it. Thank you.